# Randomize border color on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, colors, border

I have this script that randomize the color of my border img on hover, but it also removes my basic border when I leave the img..(from the start all my img have a grey border, and I'd like this border to alway stay there and not be removed)

```
script>      
$(function() {
  var colors = ["#FC3E6B","#24FF00","#0087F9","#F9F900"];

  $('.grid-item-content').hover(
    function() {
      var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);

      $(this).css('border-style', 'solid');
      $(this).css('border-width', '10px');
      $(this).css('border-color', colors[rand]);
    },
    function() {
      $(this).css('border-style', 'none');
    }
  );
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can do this easily by removing the inline style attribute

```
$(function() {
  var colors = ["#FC3E6B","#24FF00","#0087F9","#F9F900"];

  $('.grid-item-content').hover(
    function() {
      var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);
      $(this).css('border-style', 'solid');
      $(this).css('border-width', '1px');
      $(this).css('border-color', colors[rand]);
    },
    function () {
        $(this).removeAttr('style');
    }
  );
});
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jdro6qch/

Answer (score 0):

You just have to modify the second function to set the border grey.

```
<script>      
$(function() {
  var colors = ["#FC3E6B","#24FF00","#0087F9","#F9F900"];

  $('.grid-item-content').hover(
    function() {
      var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);

      $(this).css('border-style', 'solid');
      $(this).css('border-width', '10px');
      $(this).css('border-color', colors[rand]);
    },
    function() {
      $(this).css('border-style', 'solid');
      $(this).css('border-width', '10px');
      $(this).css('border-color', 'grey');
    }
  );
});
</script>
```

Comment: Perfect Thanks mate !